# Proving some identities using Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series, parsevals-identity

Find the fourier series of the following function: 
$$f:[-\pi,\pi]\to \mathbb{R} , f(x) = \pi x - x^3$$
Easy task. $a_n = 0$ since f is odd and $b_n = \dfrac{2\pi}{n}(-1)^{n+1} + \dfrac{2{\pi}^2}{n}(-1)^{n+2} +\dfrac{12}{n^3}(-1)^{n+3}$

Hopefully no mistakes have I made there.

So, $f(x) \approx \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n \sin nx$

Prove the following results: $$a) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3} = \dfrac{{\pi}^3}{32} $$
$$b)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \dfrac{1}{n^6} = \dfrac{{\pi}^6}{945}$$

I tried Parseval's identity, but it doesn't seem to lead to anything remarkable. Any tips?